# drf-spectacular: Automatic rendering of schema fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi, drf-spectacular

Is there a setting that will automatically display field data?

#### Used:

```
Django==3.0.14
drf-spectacular==0.24.2
drf-spectacular-sidecar==2022.12.1
```

#### drf-spectacular settings

```py
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA': False,
    # Permission
    'SERVE_AUTHENTICATION': ['rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication'],
    'SERVE_PERMISSIONS': ['rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'],
    # UI settings
    'SWAGGER_UI_DIST': 'SIDECAR',  # shorthand to use the sidecar instead
    'SWAGGER_UI_FAVICON_HREF': 'SIDECAR',
    'REDOC_DIST': 'SIDECAR',
    'SCHEMA_PATH_PREFIX_TRIM': True,
}
```

In the swagger, the data is reflected in this form:

[swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVB2W.png)

Is it possible to automatically expand the information of these fields?

Example like here:

[Correct answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM6Er.png)

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the settings

```
SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'SHOW_REQUEST_BODY': True,
    'SHOW_RESPONSE_BODY': True,
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_DEPTH': None,
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Need to set a setting for the Swagger UI

Decision:

```
'SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS': {
    'deepLinking': True,
    'displayOperationId': True,
    'defaultModelsExpandDepth': -1,
    'defaultModelExpandDepth': 3,
}
```

[Available the swagger UI settings](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/)